# how to handle ADO.NET DbConnection(s) in long running web service with DbDataAdapters?

Tags: c#, ado.net, reconnect, dbconnection

Basically what I do now is:

During initialization

- create connection and store it
- create DbDataAdapters and their commands with the stored connection
- call DbDataAdapter.Fill for each
  adapter to populate DataTables from database

and when handling requests

- insert/update/delete rows in DataTables
- call DbDataAdapter.Update at some point. Not necessarily every time (update uses naturally adapter's commands' connection)

Is this the correct way or should I always create a new connection when request arrives, and then assign it to DbDataAdapter.Insert/Update/DeleteCommand.Connection, before calling DbDataAdapter.Update? I'm thinking about issues like reconnecting to db after network/server problem.

Thanks & BR -Matti

Comment: it's WCF, not hosted in IIS but in Windows service. i'm actully developing only the persistence layer. I already changed the implemetation in a way that I always create new connection and before calling DbDataAdapter.Update I set Connection properties of the adapter's 3 commands. but i'm still listening what other people have to say about that and why :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you mention web services, think about concurrency. What if two or more concurrent requests are processed at your server side.

Is it ok to use the same connection? Is it ok to use the same `DataAdapter`?
The most probable answer is - it's not, it probably would not work.

Thus, the safest approach is to create a new connection and a new data adapter upon each request.

Since connections are pooled, there should be no issues with "reconnecting" - the pool serves a connection and the handshake was probably performed before. There's then no performance hit.

Comment: thanks Wiktor but concurrency is taken care of (I use thread safe singleton). I don't want to load all tables again every time request is handled so I have to use same DataSet.